# Uniqueness validation with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Having uniqueness validation on User model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message => "Email Address Already In Use. Have You Forgot Your Password?"
```

It fails to raise an error when creating a new user and being saved:

```
 user = {
         :email      => email,
         :other_attributes => other,
         }

    user = User.new(user)

    count_new_real_session(user)
    set_timezone(user)

    if user.save
        #code that is being executed (it shouldn't!)
    end
```

Although there is another user with same email, the user is saved. Any idea why the validation is not stopping the user to be saved?

More info (copy and pasted right from the database):

- user1: "email" : "borjacarranza85@gmail.com"
- user2: "email" : "borjacarranza85@gmail.com"

Comment: maybe these two users' email are not same

Comment: of course i checked and they're exactly the same

Comment: Could you provide more info? like users' email

Comment: Just added it. Anything else you miss?

Comment: open `rails console`, run `p = User.new(email: "borjacarranza85@gmail.com"); p.save`, then tell me the result.

Comment: if the validation take effect, it will return false.